# Allow Accepting more than one answer

Tags: feature-request

There was no recent (in the past one month) thread asking for this feature that I could vote for or add my comments to, so I started a new one.

The problem is that sometimes a question requires many steps to solve it, and there are many answers, say one which gives all the necessary steps and the solution but you do not understand some steps in the answer, and another answer after reading which you completely understand the first answer, but this second answer does not contain all the steps and the solutions. Sometimes, answers have hints to solve a question, and often you get a better idea to solve the question after reading all the answers.

It is not fair, in my opinion, to mark one specific answer here. Ideally, I should be able to mark 3-4 answers, if they all helped me substantially and are quality answers and there is no single answer which alone would help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Upvote what is helpful. If there isn't a single definitive answer to the question, don't accept any.

Comment: Yes, I upvoted them currently. I still feel allowing to mark 3 responses would simplify a lot of things.

Comment: @Swapnil Award them bounty then!

Comment: I would lose commenting privilege if I give a bounty. Not an option. But can we please consider what's wrong with being allowed to accept more than 1 answer?

Comment: So MANY downvotes!!! Can any of the downvoters explain why they downvoted this? What's wrong with this idea.

Comment: On posts tagged [feature-request], voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself. [Source](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 6):

> can we please consider what's wrong with being allowed to accept more than 1 answer?

First, this would change expectation of acceptance. Presently, users understand that their good, elaborate answer may end up without a checkmark if someone else posts a better one. If multiple answers can be accepted, not having a checkmark on yours feels different: the asker *could* have accepted, but decided not to. There will be more *Y U No Accept* in comments, and askers will play it safe by accepting everything they get: why not, if it makes the answerers happy?  The feature becomes meaningless through overuse.

Second, this would give the question authors too much power over the appearance of the answers. Currently, the question author has the power to put **one** answer of their choice in front of the most popular answer: sometimes this is done for a good reason, sometimes not so good. Multiple acceptances would magnify the effect: by accepting several  answers, question author would be able to drop the best one   to the very bottom if they did not like the way it was written, or had a conflict with the answerer.

Comment: So we could limit the number of answers that can be accepted? Just to two, maximum 3 when there are, say 8-10 answers."Presently, users understand that their good, elaborate answer may end up without a checkmark if someone else posts a better one." Of course, when some question does have a complete, elaborate answer which explains what the OP needs, the OP should mark only one answer. Actually, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030952/some-questions-on-basic-number-theory/1030972 to see why I am asking this.

Comment: @Swapnil The problem there is that you asked three separate questions within one. This was a **bad** idea. They should have been separate questions, and then you would be able to accept appropriate answers. Also, then the questions could have been given specific titles,  instead of the extremely vague "some questions on basic number theory".

Comment: I know that's a bad idea. But the questions were so small. I mean, I have many more questions to ask from the same question paper, and I could post 40 questions at once if I were to post them separately. I will take care that the ones requiring a somewhat detailed, thought-out answer are posted as separate questions, but very small questions related to the same topic, requiring some simple fact that I was overlooking, I feel I can post as one question. If you disagree, I may post them as separate questions as you want.

Comment: You can reduce the number of questions you ask by using Google search with parameter `site:math.stackexchange.com`. For example: [n^5-n is divisible by 30](https://www.google.com/search?q=n%5E5-n%20is%20divisible%20by%2030%20%20site:math.stackexchange.com&gws_rd=ssl) brings up more than one question identical to yours.

Comment: This, incidentally, shows another issue with combined questions: impossible to mark as duplicate because only one part matches. There are reasons why these sites have rules for posting questions and answers: to keep the information organized. You are allowed 50 questions per month (and no more than 6 per day); you are not close to the limit yet. (But if you are at the limit, and try to circumvent it by combining questions, a moderator will likely have to step in.)

Comment: Yes, I know how to do a site-specific search on Google and Bing. Why did I never think of it? Thanks. Upvoted your comments.